# Why is there white splotches on my render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I used principled bsdf on everything

[image]

Comment: These look somewhat like light sources reflecting off the surface. Do you have Metallic, Specular or Clearcoat set to high values in the Principled BSDF? Overlapping faces or UVs could also cause such artifacts. Could you show a screenshot of your UV map and you texture(s), or possibly share your .blend?

Answer (score 1):

Your glossyness must be turned up a lot in your Principled shader for the skin. Try also messing around with the sub-surface shading, since it will give some more realistic results for the skin if tuned properly.

If you only gave one material for the entire head, try making some masks and give each part of the head (skin, hair, eyes) a different material, since in the real world they all have different surfaces.

Comment: what's a decent value for those?

Comment: I'd say for the skin, put a "skin" colour into the main subsurf node and a "blood" red into the scatter colour. Then maybe set the subsurf value to about 0.1. For the eyes, just a non metallic glossy material will do and for the hair, put a rough non metallic brown.

Comment: actually you seem to have an entire texture for the model so the only colour you should worry about is the subsurf red